# Postgres Foreign Data Wrapper Program gets "child process exited with exit code 1"

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I am using Postgres 14 and Foreign Data Wrappers (file_fdw and the CREATE SERVER statement) to call some system commands and get the results. But some system commands fail with a "child process exited with exit code 1" error.  Can someone help explain why the second command fails?  Both commands run fine from a command line as the postgres user.  I am on linux.

Here is an example of one that works:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rawdata.system_ps (
  pid text,
  started text,
  cpu_pcnt text,
  mem_pcnt text,
  command text
) 
SERVER "import" options (
  PROGRAM 'ps --no-headers -e -o %p, -o lstart -o ,%C, -o %mem -o ,%c',
  FORMAT 'csv',
  HEADER 'true'
);
-- select * from rawdata.system_ps;
```

Here is an example of one that fails:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rawdata.logs (
  result text
) 
SERVER "import" options (
  PROGRAM 'sudo journalctl -u postgrest.service --since "5 min ago" -o short-iso  --no-pager',
  FORMAT 'text', --text, csv, or binary
  HEADER 'off'
);
select * from rawdata.logs;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and mention that you are using file_fdw. Ideally add the `CREATE SERVER` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo` manual says:

> Upon successful execution of a `command`, the exit status from `sudo` will be the exit status of the program that was executed.
>
> [...]
>
> If there is an authentication failure, a configuration/permission problem, or if the given `command` cannot be executed, `sudo` exits with a value of 1.  In the latter case, the error string is printed to the standard error.  If sudo cannot `stat(2)` one or more entries in the user's PATH, an error is printed to the  standard  error.

So you should look into the PostgreSQL stderr log for helpful messages.